# Flutter text overflow property does not work when there is a row within a row

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              CircleAvatar(),
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(title, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
                  Text(part),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
          ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text('btn')),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

The overflow property of the text widget doesn't work.

Wrapping the widget with flexible and expanded doesn't work either.

How should I handle text overflow when there is another row within a row?

What I want is for the text to be longer so that when it encounters a button, ...the text is processed in front of the button.

---

**First try**

Wrapping a row widget with flexible doesn't work.

[image]

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Flexible(
            child: Row(
              children: [
                CircleAvatar(),
                Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(title, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
                    Text(part),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text('btn')),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

---

**Second try**

If I replace a Row within a Row with a Wrap widget and then wrap the Wrap widget with Flexible, the text is pushed to the bottom line.

[image]

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Flexible(
            child: Wrap(
              children: [
                CircleAvatar(),
                Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(title, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
                    Text(part),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text('btn')),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need two rows, use this code:

```
              Container(
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    CircleAvatar(),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Text(title, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
                          Text(part),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text('btn')),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
```

result:

[image]

Comment: I want the CircleAvatar and column to be attached and the button to be off to the right.
If I do what you say, the text to the right of the CircleAvatar will be centered.

Comment: @nkhcode No, when you use crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start for your column, all its widgets are placed on the left. you can use text, see the screenshot I attached above

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm currently out of the office and unable to make the attempt.
It's fine if the letters are long and overflow, but if the letters are short, won't they go to the center?

Comment: @nkhcode No, as you can see in the screenshot, the second text ('part') is short and placed on the left.

Comment: I mean, if "a long text" does not overflow and is short, does that column area not go to the center?

Comment: @nkhcode no, try it

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it in about 3 hours.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the inner `Row` and `Column` with `Expanded` to get available space(constrains).

```dart
 Container(
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: [
      Expanded(
        child: Row(
          children: [
            CircleAvatar(),
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(title, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
                  Text("part"),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text('btn')),
    ],
  ),
),
```

More about [ayout/constraints](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout/constraints).